# spresenseのブートローダーの書き込みでエラーになる

Tags: spresense

Spresenseは、新規なので参考書の通りに実行しているのですが、ブートローダーの書き込みのところで、エラーになってしまいました。エラーは以下の通りです。

```
Arduino：1.8.19 (Windows 10), ボード："Spresense, MainCore, 768 KB (Default), Disabled, 115200"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "flash_writer.py", line 369, in <module>

  File "flash_writer.py", line 315, in main

  File "flash_writer.py", line 201, in cancel_autoboot

  File "flash_writer.py", line 130, in write

  File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 343, in flush

  File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 445, in out_waiting

serial.serialutil.SerialException: ClearCommError failed (PermissionError(13, '?V?X?e???????????f?o?C?X???@?\??????????B', None, 31))
```

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

以下のログを見る限り、Windows上でシリアルデバイスのエラーが発生しているようです。

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: ClearCommError failed (PermissionError(13, '?V?X?e???????????f?o?C?X???@?\??????????B', None, 31))
```

一番最後の31という番号はWindows上のエラー番号で、以下のページを参考にすると、ERROR_GEN_FAILUREのようですね。
[システム エラー コード (0 から 499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

```
ERROR_GEN_FAILURE

31 (0x1F)

システムに接続されたデバイスが動作していません。
```

何らかの理由でデバイスドライバが壊れてしまっているようなので、ドライバを再度インストールしてみると解決するかもしれません。
一旦既存のドライバをデバイスマネージャから「デバイスのアインインストール」で削除し、再度[1.3. USB ドライバのインストール](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_usb_%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%90%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)のページの通りインストールしなおしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 回答をありがとうございます。実は回答を頂く前にブートローダーの書き込みができなかった新しい方のPCを使わずに、古いノートPCを使って書き込みをトライしたところ、書き込みが成功してしまいました。新しいPCでの書き込みができない理由は不明のままです。頂いた回答を拝見すると、エラーコードの意味やドライバを再度インストールしてみる方法など今後のために有益な答えが得られて感謝しております。今後ともよろしくお願い致します。